# What is the best coding standard to perform a webpage back?

Tags: javascript, html, back, browser-history

What is better to use: `history.back();`, `history.go(-1);`, a new request entirely, or something completely different?

What is the real difference between `history.go(-1);` and `history.back();`?

What is the best way to keep reliable performance (pages load without skipping or pushing forward), data integrity (loading a page as if it was a refresh, but keeping the request), but adhere to good coding practices?

Comment: According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history) there is no difference. However, you may be interested in the [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

Comment: history.back() is just a shortcut to history.go(-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MDN standards `history.back();` is equalant to pressing back button and `history.go(-1);` is equalant or shortcut for `history.back();`. If you are using so many page navigations in one code
(For example,
 `history.go(1) //forward;` 
 `history.go(-2) //go back two pages;`  
consider using `history.back();` to aviod confusion.